How can I minimized NPF photo quality from full-res to 500px?
The photo cannot load and squashed my photo into a rectangle when I used Infinity Scroll. I tried to solve the problem with CSS width and height but it rather changed the size, not the quality of the photo. What I meant is that I would like drop the photo's quality from the NPF-post type (Full resolution to 500px) as in quality, not the size it appeared on my blog. Thank you!
NPF example post:
<div class="text-post">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <div class="npf_row"><div class="npf_col"><figure class="tmblr-full"><a class="post_media_photo_anchor" data-big-photo="https://64.media.tumblr.com/efbed04ebed2742af3beb82d3817bc0b/408a90b1615169a7-3c/s1280x1920/2130929eda5b4f80d326a28b40241f28a2b1d973.jpg" data-big-photo-height="4032" data-big-photo-width="3024">
                        </div>

HTML
{block:Text}
                    <div class="text-post">
                        <h3>{Title}</h3>
                        {Body}
                    </div>
                    {block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}" title="permalink"><img id="permalink-icon" align="center" width="20px" src="https://static.tumblr.com/siia3cb/0frs4664t/diacetyl.png"></a>&ensp;<strong class="note-count" style="{color:Text}">{NoteCount}</strong>{/block:IndexPage}
                {/block:Text}

CSS
        .text-post {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .text-post img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

